# How do I make a .jar file with a .jar file?

Tags: java, jar

I'm creating a program that makes "candy".jars and I need to make this "candy".jar with a creator.jar file.  The idea is you run the creator.jar file and you can adjust settings inside of it in order to make another "candy".jar.  The problem is: I don't know if this is possible, and all of my research (i.e. google search) has come up blank.

Q. Is is possible to make a .jar file with another .jar file?

Comment: Why don´t you create your .jar files through building your projects? I can not imagine your use case...

Comment: @NoureddineOuertani I'm making a template so I can mass produce this "candy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute a process and give al param all the information as if you were generating the jar in the terminal

## Example:

compile:

**javac HelloWorld.java**

generate the jar:

**jar cfm HelloWorld.jar Manifest.txt HelloWorld.class**

run the jar: (if you need that)

**java -jar HelloWorld.jar**

you need to get a process and give as stringCommand parameter those 3 lines I posted above

```
final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(stringCommand);
```